# Ruby on rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In controller I have got this:

```
def output
  if params[:find]
    result
  elsif params[:print_db]
    print_db
  end
end
```

And the test doesn't want to enter in params[:find] condition.

Test controller:

```
test "should get 5 5 1 for view with 5 5 1 3 3" do
  get :output, {str: "5 5 1 3 3 5"}, :params => 'find'
  assert_equal assigns[:result], "5, 5, 1"
end
```

Please, help me!

Comment: You need to send a `find` param, e.g., `find: true` or something. Put a pry/etc in your controller and actually look at your params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to have both: A `params[:str]` and a `params[:find]` parameter.

Change:

```
get :output, {str: "5 5 1 3 3 5"}, :params => 'find'
```

to:

```
get :output, str: '5 5 1 3 3 5', find: true
```

Because your version passes the `:params => 'find'` part into the `session` variable not into the `params`. You might want to read in the [Rails' guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests) about what parameters the `get` method accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
get :output, { str: "5 5 1 3 3 5", find: true }
```

In your request you send only the `str` with the value `"5 5 1 3 3 5"` and no `find` parameter. You have to put all parameters into the first hash.